# mount a block device without root permission programmatically

Tags: c, linux, root, mount

I want to mount a block device, especially, optical drives, for instance, /dev/sr0 (or /dev/cdrom) in my application (wrtten in C++) in Linux in order to read each file from the device.
I found a mount() function and wrote next code:

```
mount("/dev/sr0", "/path/to/mount/point", "udf", MS_RDONLY, "");
```

It works very well ONLY IF I have root permission, which is not usual case.

Since desktop environments(e.g., KDE) can mount USB/CD/DVDs without permission, I thought maybe there's an interface to allow this such as D-Bus protocol, but I couldn't find.

Is it impossible to mount a device without root-permission programmatically?
Or, am I missing something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is it impossible to mount a device without root-permission programmatically?

Yes, it is not possible.

From [`man 2 mount`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html):

> Appropriate privilege (Linux: the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability) is required to mount file systems.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but I didn't ask how to call mount() function without root-permission. What I asked is how to mount a device without root-permission programmatically. mount() is just an example of failed try. Isn't there any other way to mount?

Comment: @xylosper: No, there isn't

Comment: Actually, that's wrong in modern Linux systems, either via the "user" option in fstab for specific mounts, or using things like gvfs-mount. http://askubuntu.com/a/191093 has a good explanation with options.